# Does a line intersect a box in a 3D space?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Known parameters:

- Coordinates of the $8$ corners of the box: $\{(X_1;Y_1;Z_1), ..., (X_8;Y_8;Z_8)\}$
- The box is alligned with the global coordinate system
- Begin and end coordinates of the line: $\{(X_b;Y_b;Z_b),(X_e;Y_e;Z_e)\}$

---

> Is there a general way to calculate this for the whole box at once or do I
>   have to calculate if there's an intersection for every single face
>   of the box?

If it should be calculated for every face I already found how to calculate the [intersection from the line with the plane of the face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection). This will raise the next question:

> How do I determine if an intersection point with the plane is an
>   intersection with the face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for a general method, so here we go:

Let $g$ be the line and let $H_1^+,H_1^-$ be the planes bounding your box in the first direction, $H_2^+,H_2^-$ and $H_3^+,H_3^-$ the planes for the 2nd and 3rd direction respectively.

Now find w.l.o.g $\lambda_1^+\leq\lambda_1^-$ (otherwise flip the roles of $H_1^+$ and $H_1^-$) such that $g\left(\lambda_1^+\right)\in H_1^+$ and $g\left(\lambda_1^-\right)\in H_1^-$ (take $\lambda_1^+=-\infty$ and $\lambda_1^-=+\infty$ for $g\parallel H_1^+$)

Analogeous get $\lambda_2^+\leq\lambda_2^-$ and $\lambda_3^+\leq\lambda_3^-$.

Now check for existence of $\lambda$ such that $\max\left(\lambda_1^+,\lambda_2^+,\lambda_3^+\right)\leq\lambda\leq\min\left(\lambda_1^-,\lambda_2^-,\lambda_3^-\right)$.

If there is no such $\lambda$ your line doesn't cut the box.

**remark**

- you will find explicit formulae for $\lambda_1^+,...,\lambda_3^-$.
- if $\lambda$ equals $\lambda_1^+$ then $g\left(\lambda\right)$ is in $H_1^+$ and so on.
- in the case of the box being aligned with the coordinate system, calculating $\lambda_1^+$ and $\lambda_1^-$ would only need information of the first component of $g$ and is thus easy. You do not even need matrix calculus in that simple case.
- I use $\lambda_1^+$ to indicate that $g$ is *entering* the region bounded by $H_1^+$ and $H_1^-$ at $\lambda_1^+$. (analogeously it is exiting at $\lambda_1^-$)
- given a point $x$ you can check if it is inside of a convex polygon by checking if for each bounding plane $P=y+V$ ($V$ is a Plane containing $0$, y is a Vector inside the Plane $P$) with outer normal vector $n$ holds that the inner product $\left<x-y,n\right>$ is negative.
- if you want to check if a point is in the inner of a convex polygon generally you have to check if it is in the inner (given an outer normal direction) of each bounding plane. If you find *one* plane such that it is on the outside you are already done and can stop.

Comment: Seems right what I need, I'll accept it as an answer once I've tried it out!

Comment: With "Calculating $\lambda_1^+$ and $\lambda_1^-$ would only need information of the first component of $g$", do you mean $g$ is written parametric ($g(t)$) and I only need the $x = ...$ part if the $1$ index refers to the plane with normal x-axis ?

Comment: yes, exactly that.

Comment: Programmed it and it works really great. Do you have any thoughts on how I can apply this for a line with a begin and an end?

Comment: yes. I would represent the line as convex hull of their end points $\left\{L(\lambda):=\lambda\cdot x_{\text{start}}+(1-\lambda)\cdot x_{\text{end}} : 0\leq\lambda\leq 1\right\}$ and then consider cases: (I) both ends in cube, line completely insite (II) one end in cube, find smallest $\lambda\in[0,1]$ such that $L(\lambda)$ in any plane and on the "inside direction" with respect to the other planes, one line segment inside

Comment: (III) no end inside, find $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in[0,1]$ such that $L(\lambda_1),L(\lambda_2)$ in any plane and on the "inside-direction" with respect to all other planes, line segment inside (VI) $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ dont exist, nothing inside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the slabs method that is often used in ray-tracing?

http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rtinter3.htm